# Listview delete item from Database

Tags: android, database, listview, android-activity

Hey. I have the following code:

```
final String text = (String) lt.getItemAtPosition(position); 
                    db.removeCategory(text);
```

What I want to do is to remove a item from a ListView. The problem I have is that I only can remove the item that is in the first position of the list.

Is like the `getItemAtPosition(0);`

Why's that? Can somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: Could you collaborate a little more on the problem? I guess you have a ListView which has elements from a database? Do you want to remove the item just from the list or from the database as well? And please provide more code.

Comment: Try this : remove final from final String text=....

Comment: text =lt.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()


I got it. Now it's Working.

Thanks

Comment: what is  db.removeCategory()? is that your custom function? If yes, post that code as well. Elaborate your code and situation to help you more.

Comment: the remove category is a method in a class DBAdapter that removes data from the database.

Comment: Post your code where you set Position variable. It is likely being set incorrectly to first node every time

Comment: {adb.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
     
     public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int arg) {
      
      db.open();
      
      text= lt.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
      db.removeCategory(text);
      aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
      
      Toast.makeText(
        getApplicationContext(),
        "Dados Removidos com Sucesso!!! "
        + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(category.this, MenuPrincipal.class);
         startActivity(myIntent);
     }});}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your array to ArrayAdapter and use its remove method to remove particular object. Refer this link to get some understanding of how it works.

[Remove ListView items in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558591/how-to-remove-listview-items-in-android)

Comment: my problem is that it only removes the first position of the list. Whatever item i click, the only item that is removed is the first.

Comment: If it only removes the first one, your `position`'variable is likely wrong. Please post how you get it..

Comment: `public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int arg) {
      
      db.open();
      
      text= lt.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
      db.removeCategory(text);
      aa.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add items into a collection or data datable and then bind it to ListView.

In ste removal phase you delete the item from the collection/data table instead direct one from the ListView.

Comment: text =lt.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()


I got it. Now it's Working.

Thanks anyway

Comment: can you explain me that with more detail?