# Remove a specific row from listview?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview

I'm trying to remove a specific row from listview, but my app keeps crashing.

First, I tried removing item form listAdapter only, but it crashes:

```
listAdapter.remove(listAdapter.getItem(toDelete));
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Then I also tried removing it from listView directly but it also crashes:

```
listView.removeViewAt(toDelete);
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

toDelete is an integer variable that has a number id of the row that I'm clicking.

So how could I delete a specific row from listview?

This is the full code, if anyone wants it:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            deleteAlert.setTitle("Warning");
            deleteAlert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
            toDelete = arg2;
            deleteAlert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    File directory = new File (externalStoragePath + File.separator + "Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/");
                    File deleteFile = new File (directory, fileNames.get(toDelete) + ".mp3");
                    deleteFile.delete();
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    listView.removeViewAt(toDelete);
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.i("TAG", "Deleting file: " + directory + fileNames.get(toDelete) + ".mp3");
                }
            });
```

It's really hard to expand the "it crashes" part. It's simple: as soon as I click the "yes" button, the app crashes. Here's the logcat file if it helps:

```
08-06 19:05:07.437: E/AndroidRuntime(16257): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 19:05:07.437: E/AndroidRuntime(16257): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
08-06 19:05:07.437: E/AndroidRuntime(16257):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
08-06 19:05:07.437: E/AndroidRuntime(16257):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
08-06 19:05:07.437: E/AndroidRuntime(16257):    at com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.RecordedLibrary$2$1.onClick(RecordedLibrary.java:113)
08-06 19:05:07.437: E/AndroidRuntime(16257):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
08-06 19:05:07.437: E/AndroidRuntime(16257):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 19:05:07.437: E/AndroidRuntime(16257):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 19:05:07.437: E/AndroidRuntime(16257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-06 19:05:07.437: E/AndroidRuntime(16257):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 19:05:07.437: E/AndroidRuntime(16257):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-06 19:05:07.437: E/AndroidRuntime(16257):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-06 19:05:07.437: E/AndroidRuntime(16257):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-06 19:05:07.437: E/AndroidRuntime(16257):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Well the error is self-explanatory. Your arraylist has a size of 0. Have you tried any of the suggestions [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5344958/645270)?

Comment: `listAdapter.remove(listAdapter.getItem(toDelete));` is the proper way. Can you post your adapter code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue! It was completely my fault, I'm a shallow guy.

The problam was that I called dialog.dismiss() before deleting rows. I simply moved the dialog.dismiss() at the end of the onclick and now it works as it should :)

This is the code now:

```
deleteAlert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    File directory = new File (externalStoragePath + File.separator + "Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/");
                    File deleteFile = new File (directory, fileNames.get(toDelete) + ".mp3");
                    deleteFile.delete();
                    Log.i("TAG", "Deleting file: " + directory + fileNames.get(toDelete) + ".mp3");

                    listAdapter.remove(listAdapter.getItem(toDelete));
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the crash is not because of removing, it's about updating.

The key thing is

```
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You can't do it inside

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
{
}
```

Since it's outside the UIThread(some people call it Main Thread), you can only modify UI inside the UI Thread. `notifyDataSetChanged()` is gonna to modify the UI.

To solve this, you can use a Handler instead. 
Do it like this:

```
**Handler myHandler = new Handler()
{
   public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg)
   {
      listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
};**
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            deleteAlert.setTitle("Warning");
            deleteAlert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
            toDelete = arg2;
            deleteAlert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    File directory = new File (externalStoragePath + File.separator + "Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/");
                    File deleteFile = new File (directory, fileNames.get(toDelete) + ".mp3");
                    deleteFile.delete();
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    listView.removeViewAt(toDelete);
                    **myHandler.sendMessage();**
                    Log.i("TAG", "Deleting file: " + directory + fileNames.get(toDelete) + ".mp3");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time and reply, but I found a simpler solution (check my answer) :)