# To remove the single item in listview in android?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have to remove the single item from list view in android while clicking long click. Please let me suitable code for removing a item in list view?
Here is the my code

```
        this.getListView().setLongClickable(true);
        this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto - generated method stub

            }
}
```

Comment: Bad formatted code, you miss one parenthesis and also nothing has been done by you.

Comment: Provide the full info like which adapter you are using and how the data you are passing to the adapter?

Comment: You should look http://stackoverflow.com/a/28137409/1881611

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove ListView items in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558591/remove-listview-items-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Use remove() method in your ArrayAdapter.

```
yourarrayAdapter.remove(yourarrayAdapter.getItem([POSITION]));
```

OR

```
yourarrayList.remove([POSITION]);
yourarrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your click callback, to remove the view from its parent:

```
((ViewManager) parent).removeView(view);
```