# Dynamically Delete an element from listview - Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to delete an element from the list when a button x is clicked on the layout of a list element.
Here is my java code, onNext() is working for adding an element to the list . but the onDelete isnt working.The textView4 element has numbers starting from 1 to n when new elements are added

```js
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list2);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList.add("1");
        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list2_layout, R.id.textView4, arrayList);

        ListView myList2 = (ListView)
                findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        myList2.setAdapter(adapter2);


    }

    public void onNextItem(View v)
    {

            counter++;
            String str=Integer.toString(counter);
            arrayList.add(str);
        adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    public void onDeleteItem(View v2)
    {

        arrayList.remove(R.id.textView4);
        adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove ListView items in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558591/remove-listview-items-in-android)

Comment: if you just want to delete the last added item use: `arrayList.remove(arrayList.size()-1);`

Answer (score 1):

you should not be passing the `R.id.textView4` to remove the 4th textView

```
 arrayList.remove(R.id.textView4);
```

You will need to do something like `arrayList.remove(4);` to delete the forth element from the list

Comment: Ok, I tried that but the app closes down on doing that

Answer (score 1):

on `onNextItem(View v)`:

you **are adding an `integer(counter) converted to string` to the list**(`arrayList.add(str);`)

but on `onDeleteItem(View v2)`:

you are **trying to remove a `view` from the list** (`arrayList.remove(R.id.textView4);`)

Comment: Ok, how do I delete an element then?
Thanks

Comment: you can do remove  item from `ArrayList`  and `notifyDataSetChanged` as said by @Dominic D'Souza

Comment: @AsifMuhammad instead of `arrayList.remove(R.id.textView4);` write `arrayList.remove(StringYouWantToRemove);`

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to remove Textview

```
arrayList.remove(R.id.textView4);
```

do it like this

```
arrayList.remove(clickeditempostion);
adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
arrayList.remove(CURRENT_INDEX_OF_ARRAYLIST);
        adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
```