# view only specific items in grid view android

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

Hey I am trying to view specific items in the grid view which have an id less than 100. This  is my adapter class but for some reason its not working and displays all the items. 
Logged in the id's and they are all fine.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    PreviousViewHolder holder = null;
    ServerFeed previousDayRank = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        if (previousDayRank.getId() < 100) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popular_discover_list_item, null);
            holder = new PreviousViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.null_item, null);
            holder = new PreviousViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

    } else {

        holder = (PreviousViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.setImageUrl(getContext(), previousDayRank.getName(), previousDayRank.getId());
    }
    return convertView;

}
```

I have tried varieos links [link1](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiT9trMtoPUAhVBPY8KHcf_ADgQFggwMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F5497580%2Fhow-to-dynamically-remove-items-from-listview-on-a-button-click&usg=AFQjCNH-wgmYUxISim6EPufhAJdhQiWW3g) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558591/remove-listview-items-in-android) but they didn't really help

Comment: may i know what happened after run your code?

Comment: you can filter your dataset before setting it to adapter because adapter will populate views as much your data count which invoked in getItemCount

Comment: It showed all the items. in and not just the one's with less the id 100 @YuvaanChauhan

Answer (score 0):

Change your getView method like this

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)                {
        PreviousViewHolder holder = null;
        ServerFeed previousDayRank = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {           
 convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popular_discover_list_item, null);
                holder = new PreviousViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {

                holder = (PreviousViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

            }

        if(previousDayRank.getId() < 100){
        holder.setImageUrl(getContext(), previousDayRank.getName(), previousDayRank.getId());}
       return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: hey your code worked it does not show the those items but it still has those items which were meant to be removed  they are just not visible

Answer (score 0):

Just filter your data before passing to addapter. Just like that:

```
for(ServerFeed item : mServerFeeds){if(item.getId() > 100) mServerFeeds.remove(item);}
```

Answer (score 0):

call this method in your code-

```
public int getItemPosition(long id)
{
for (int position=0; position<100; position++)
    if (mList.get(position).getId() == id)
        return position;
return 0;
}
```